# Erro ao inserir loop de imagem em relatorio pdf reports.dll .net

Tags: .net, vb.net, loop

Tenho um while que irá repetir 3 vezes uma inserção de um codigo de barras
porém estou usando a lib reports.dll para criar o relatorio em pdf.
Essa lib aceita apenas imagens salvas em algum diretorio(até onde sei),
mas no momento que vou inserir novamente a imagem já criada ele me retorna um erro :

> O processo não pode acessar o arquivo 'C:\cod.jpeg' porque ele está
>   sendo usado por outro processo

```
Dim Chave = "858300000009330003101607570100361164044015053000"
Dim barcode As New BarcodeLib.Barcode()
Dim img As Bitmap = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128C, Chave)
img.Save("C:\cod.jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

linhaPreencheCont = 15

Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < 3

PDFPage.Add(35, linhaPreencheCont, New RepImage("C:\cod.jpeg", 300, 40))

linhaPreencheCont +=60
end while
```

---

Já tentei também criar um novo objeto bitmap a cada volta no laço, mas tenho um novo erro:

> Erro genérico de GDI+

```
Dim Chave = "858300000009330003101607570100361164044015053000"
Dim barcode As New BarcodeLib.Barcode()


dim linhaPreencheCont as integer = 15
Dim i As Integer = 0

While i < 3

Dim img As Bitmap = New Bitmap(barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128C, Chave))
img.Save("C:\cod.jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

PDFPage.Add(35, linhaPreencheCont, New RepImage("C:\cod.jpeg", 300, 40))

linhaPreencheCont +=60
end while
```

Answer (score 0):

Para que isso dê certo, é preciso converter a imagem para um memoryStream 
Segue o código:

```
Dim Chave = "858300000009330003101607570100361164044015053000"
Dim barcode As New BarcodeLib.Barcode()
Dim img As Bitmap = barcode.Encode(BarcodeLib.TYPE.CODE128C, Chave)
img.Save("C:\cod.jpeg", Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)

linhaPreencheCont = 15

Dim i As Integer = 0
While i < 3
  Dim fileImg As Byte() = IO.File.ReadAllBytes("C:\cod.jpeg")
  Dim memory As New MemoryStream(fileImg)

PDFPage.Add(35, linhaPreencheCont, New RepImage(memory , 300, 40))

linhaPreencheCont +=60
end while
```